# How do I open or install exe files in Whonix, or can you not?

Tags: whonix

I'm trying to install Hexchat on Whonix, but the download gave me an exe file that is asking me what to open it with. What do I open it with? Do I have to download Unix/Linux version or what?

Answer (score 2):

Correct.

[For most that matters, you're in the same situation as a user of Debian GNU/Linux](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/About#Based_on_Debian).

You need either:

- (best) a version of that that is compatible with GNU/Linux / Debian Linux available from Debian's APT repository for simple and secure installation
- (more difficult) a version of that that is compatible with GNU/Linux / Debian Linux available from external APT sources or source code
- (workaround) [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29)
- (if all cords break and you really find no alternative Linux version) a [Whonix-Custom-Workstation](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Other_Operating_Systems)

[In context of Whonix and anonymity, XChat is recommended as IRC chat application.](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/XChat)

See also:

- https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Install_Software
- https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Documentation